# Sql Query to update data by prepending text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with following data :-

[image]

I want to change data of SetType Column as 'CATEGORY_3'. So the number will remain as it is, i need to prepend the number with text 'CATEGORY_'.

so SetType values will be like following :-

```
CATEGORY_3
CATEGORY_3
CATEGORY_5
CATEGORY_5
```

How to update data by prepeding predefined text by SQL Query?

Comment: `set SetType = 'CATEGORY_' + SetType`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `update`.  Here is one method:

```
update t
    set SetType = replace('Category_@val', '@val', SetType);
```

This assumes that `SetType` is a character field.  If not, you will need to alter the type of the column before making such a change.

Answer (score 0):

Use UPDATE statement of all rows :

```
UPDATE your_tablename SET SetType = 'CATEGORY_'+SetType
```

IF SetType datatype is not in VARCHAR means use below query :

```
UPDATE your_tablename SET SetType = 'CATEGORY_'+CAST(SetType AS VARCHAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CONCAT`.

```
update table_name set SetType = CONCAT('CATEGORY_', SetType)
```

`CONCAT` will simply append strings to one another and you can use multiple strings in argument by separating it with `,` .

Answer (score 0):

Use UPDATE statement, But if your SetType columns Data Type is Int then first convert it into varchar.

```
   UPDATE your_tablename 
   SET SetType = 'CATEGORY_'+ CONVERT(NVarchar(2),SetType)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `SetType` is currently an `integer` type, it is probably an `int` for a reason. If you only need certain queries to prepend `'Category_'` modify your `select` queries instead of the updating the table.

```
select 
    SetName
  , SetType = convert(varchar(20),('Category_'+convert(varchar(11),SetType)))
  , FieldValue1
from t
```